# How do I use .NET 3.0 in VS2005?

Tags: visual-studio-2005, c#-3.0, automatic-properties

I am trying to use Auto-implemented properties in VS2005.  I have .NET 3.0 framework loaded on my machine, but Visual Studio is still compiling with .NET 2.0.  How do I tell it to use .NET 3.0?

Comment: I think that you mean C# 3.0, not .NET 3.0, since auto-implemented properties were added in C# 3.0 (which shipped with .NET 3.5). .NET 3.0 was the WPF/WCF/WF release.

Comment: Wow, nice and straight forward are the releases,  Thanks Andy, I think the is the answer I needed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't think it is possible to do this, since that is a feature of the C# compiler. Visual Studio 2005 is hard-coded to use the C# 2.0 compiler. You need to upgrade to Visual Studio 2008 to use the new C# 3.0 features.

Comment: .NET 3.0 was released before vs2008, how were we to use the new framework when it was released?

Comment: At the time, there was a WPF CTP, and a WCF CTP that added the ability to write .NET 3.0 apps to VS2005. Since VS2008 supports them by default, those CTPs are no longer supported.

Answer (score 3):

Autogenerated properties require C#3.0 which isn't available in VS2005.  You need to use VS2008 to get the autogenerated property syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your project properties. Under the application tab you can change your Target Framework

Comment: You can only change the target framework in VS2008 (and later, I presume). The OP is using VS2005.

Comment: This is an ASP.NET project, I don't see the option you indicated above.

Comment: Wow, I'm not sure how I missed that. It's been a long week - my apologies